# Is there any way to use special character when define a new ojbect

Tags: c#, httprequest, restsharp

I'm writing a bot, need to add a json parameters in my post request
The issue i face that some time the parameters i want to send contains special characters example below descripe my full problem

In my example below i face error with params predefined variable in with c# and with special char

```
object parameters =
{
        [username] = "user",
        params = "param"
};

PostRequest(Url, parameters);
```

Comment: Try prefixing it with `@`, ie: `@params = "param"`. By the way it isn't a "special character", it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: I would suggest using a concrete class rather than an anonymous object and use the `JsonProperty` attribute to control the JSON output.

Comment: I don't think that's how you make an anonymous object anyways. It's `var abc = new { ... };`.

Comment: Yeah, we need more information on what you are doing here, neither of the properties you use here will work like this, and even if they did you are missing the `new` keyword.

Comment: @RonBeyer thanks the `@` char made it for the `params` predefined in c#

Comment: @DavidG for the part of special car how could i made below code acceptable in c#

`object new obj= {
       social[google-login] = "username"
}`

Comment: Why do you want that, it makes no sense? What JSON output are you trying to create here?

Comment: Here is the request i want to emulate `https://i.ibb.co/5x1ChQs/image.png`
Is there any way to do it in Restsharp instead of sending it as object ??

Answer (score 1):

You should use a json object and then serialize it into your request like so

```
public class Params
{
    public string cnt { get; set; }
    public string lastGlobalMessageTime { get; set; }
    public int lastId { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string __invalid_name__social[google-login] { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public Params @params { get; set; }
    public string session { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create an instance of that class and assign your values accordingly

```
RootObject parameters = new RootObject();

parameters.social[google-login] = socialLoginVariable;
parameters.action = ActionVariable;
...
```

**Note:** I used json2csharp it tells you that `social[google-login]` is invalid and does not make sense, you could remove `__invalid_name__` and just use `social[google-login]` and see if that will work for you